# XPath to get siblings between two elements

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, mechanize

With the following markup I need to get the middle tr's

```
<tr class="H03">
  <td>Artist</td>
  ...
<tr class="row_alternate">
  <td>LIMP</td>
  <td>Orion</td>
  ...
</tr>
<tr class="row_normal">
  <td>SND</td>
  <td>Tender Love</td>
  ...
</tr>
<tr class="report_total">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  ...
</tr>
```

That is every sibling tr between `<tr class="H03">` and `<tr class="report_total">`. I'm scraping using mechanize and nokogiri, so am limited to their xpath support. My best attempt after looking at various StackOverflow questions is

```
page.search('/*/tr[@class="H03"]/following-sibling::tr[count(. | /*/tr[@class="report_total"]/preceding-sibling::tr)=count(/*/tr[@class="report_total"]/preceding-sibling::tr)]')
```

which returns an empty array, and is so ridiculously complicated that my limited xpath fu is completely overwhelmed!.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following xpath :

```
//tr[@class='H03']/following-sibling::tr[following-sibling::tr[@class='report_total']]
```

Above xpath select all `<tr>` following `tr[@class='H03']`, where `<tr>` have following sibling `tr[@class='report_total']` or in other words selected `<tr>` are located before `tr[@class='report_total']`.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize has a few helper methods here that would be useful to employ.

presuming you are doing something like the following:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.website.com')
start_tr = page.at('.H03')
```

At this point, tr will be a nokogiri xml element of the first tr you list in your question.

You can then iterate through siblings with:

```
next_tr = start_tr.next_sibling
```

Do this until you hit the tr at which you want to stop.

```
trs = Array.new

until next_tr.attributes['class'].name == 'report_total'
    next_tr = next_tr.next_sibling
    trs << next_tr
end
```

If you want the range to be inclusive of the start and stop trs (H03 and report_total) just tweak the code above to include them in the trs array.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. This works great and introduced me to stuff in mechanize I wasn't familar with.